# Date object and ISO date object return different dates

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, datetime, mongodb-query

I need to capture a date value, parse it to an ISODate and then query a mongoDB collection that stores an object with a date value. The query checks for equality between the date of an event and matches it against a function that determines if the date will fall on a weekend. Everything works, however if the date falls on a Monday, it will also come through on the results.

Something I have noticed is the date object moves back a day when we use toISOString:

**Date Obj**

```
Mon Apr 18 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (BST)
```

**toISOString:**

```
2016-04-17T23:00:00.000Z
```

Notice it now has the 17th as the date?

**This inconsistency exists in the DB as well:**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56fe91afceb044f551dbffce"),
    "url" : "http://www.timeoutshanghai.com/features/Blog-Food__Drink/35271/Baristas-showcase-latte-art-in-Shanghai.html",
    "title" : "Baristas showcase latte art in Shanghai - Blog - Time Out - Shanghai",
    "selectedDate" : ISODate("2016-04-17T23:00:00Z"), 
    "__v" : 0
}
```

This should give `selectedDate" : ISODate("2016-04-17T23:00:00Z")`

However if we log the collection to the console, the date is returned as a Monday:

```
  { _id: 56fe91c5ceb044f551dbffcf,
    url: 'http://www.timeoutshanghai.com/features/Blog-Food__Drink/35271/Baristas-showcase-latte-art-in-Shanghai.html',
    title: 'Baristas showcase latte art in Shanghai - Blog - Time Out - Shanghai',
    selectedDate: Mon Apr 18 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (BST),
    __v: 0 },
```

This becomes an issue when I query the DB to only return events on a weekend as the Monday's are slipping through.

Comment: The key is `BST`.  Midnight on day X in BST is 23:00 on day X-1 in UTC (GMT). It's just a time zone difference.

Comment: It's the same date but displayed with two different timezones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have 2 different timezones:

- `toISOString()` returns the date formatted in UTC+00:00, which is indicated by the `Z` flag at the end `2016-04-17T23:00:00.000Z`.
- Your date object `Mon Apr 18 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (BST)` (probably formatted using `toString()`) is formatted in you current timezone: GMT+01:00.

That's why you get this difference in 1 hour.
Read more about the [iso date format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

Comment: Okay makes sense. The second date is the one I really need, is there a way to offset the UTC timezone?

Comment: @RhysEdwards You'll need a helper function, or the best to use `moment` library.